# Working with Ext Js 4.0 Accordion layout

Tags: javascript, extjs

I am using Ext Js 4.0 and using 3 grid panel added in a panel with Accordion layout.

One button outside of these panels is kept and I want that when it is clicked, the current expanded panel's selected rows data is fetched.

In order to fetch data from an individual panel's grid, I have used the following code:

```
lside.items.items[0].getSelectionModel().getSelection()[0].data
```

(`lside` is the panel with Accordion layout).

The problem is that I don't know and I can't figure out how to determine which panel is expanded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how I missed it but `getCollapsed` method of panel helped me to determine which panel is active

Just need to loop through all panels and check which panel's `getCollapsed` returns false as result

Answer (score 0):

Expanded panel must have one (or maybe more) additional css class - check it with firebug. By checking if html element has this class, you can determine if panel is expanded.

Comment: Well I did thought of it and tried but name of css class of this panel are quite long so didn't indulge in it

Is there any other known option ?

Comment: you can add a hidden div with and check if it's visible

Comment: ok . I'll check that way and get back then . Thank you for suggestion

Comment: sorry, not hidden - I meant empty ; )